# How to calculate line spacing based on font's line height in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, fonts, uilabel

You can set the line spacing for attributed text in labels by the following code:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "My text")

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

// line spacing in points
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1.5

attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
 value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))


label.attributedText = attributedString
```

But whenever I check the design, I face something named `Line Height` for font which is in different scale, for example:

```
Font Size: 14pt
Line Height: 18pt
```

How can I convert the number to paragraph line spacing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. You can calculate the line spacing as follows:

```
Line Spacing = (Line Height - Font Size) / 2
```

Comment: I know this an old question and you found a solution, but are you sure this is correct? I think the formula for line spacing is actually `lineHeight / fontSize`. For example, if the font size is 16 and the line height is 24 in your design program, you'd use `paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 24 / 16` or simply `paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1.5`.